# DIfferent Behavior in SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I'm trying to update some data like

```
if Exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'Enabled' 
          and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'SLBPool'))
      begin
            update SLBPool set SLBPool.Enabled=1
      End
GO
```

it shows error "**Invalid column name 'Enabled**'" in SQL 2012,however ,not happened with 2008 R2
how come ?

Comment: Error seems to indicate that your `SLBPool` table doesnt have a column called `Enabled` in your 2012 db. You absolutely sure the schema's of both the `SLBPool` tables are the same?

Comment: Possibly the schema on the system views changed?  Collation or data type could be wrong too.

Comment: Is it possible that `Enabled` is a reserved word in 2012, but not in 2008?  For instance, you can name a column `Values`, but you have to always enclose it in brackets like this `[Values]`.  Is it the same with `[Enabled]`?

Comment: This should have been an error on 2008 as well. When the batch containing this code is compiled, the *entire* batch is compiled, and the absence of the `Enabled` column should always cause an error. I'd be interested in seeing a repro script where this actually works as you intended.

Comment: Sorry ! it is too late to re-produce the error. I had dropped the table and recreate a new one,then everything goes well now.
but , I were sure that the column 'Enabled' is not exist !! is should not show any error in 2012.
thanks all the replys

Comment: hello,guys,check the answers i had given, Damien_The_Unbeliever is right!! not a sql version concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this should work on any version of SQL Server (certainly as far back as 2000, IIRC) is if you prevent the statement from being compiled until after you've evaluated the if condition - which would indicate dynamic SQL:

```
if Exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'Enabled' 
          and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'SLBPool'))
      begin
            exec sp_executesql 'update SLBPool set SLBPool.Enabled=1'
      End
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is because of collation prefs of server instance, check if this works, or produces some other error:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = N'Enabled' 
          AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'SLBPool'))
      BEGIN
            UPDATE SLBPool SET SLBPool.Enabled = 1
      END
GO
```